# Make Safari Open all Links in Same Tab

Tags: macos, safari

I have seen (and am using) the "hack" to make Safari open links in a new tab that would normally open in a new window, but now what I am looking for is a way to make links that should open in a new window open in the same window and tab, and only open a new one when I tell it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Greasemonkey (GreaseKit is the port Safari) script will accomplish "all links in same window/tab" functionality:  http://naruzo.vox.com/library/post/greasekit-script-to-open-all-links-in--same--tab-killtargets.html

Comment: I actually ended up writing a similar script: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/72994 Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Check the Safari preferences. There are two settings. First is in **General** panel that controls links from other apps. The second is in the **Tabs** panel. You can set which key modifier is used to open a link in a new tab vs. a new window. *Command + click* is the default to open a link in a new tab.

Comment: I am not looking for how to open links in a new tab. I am looking for how to make the default behaviour for all links to be open in the same window/tab, like how most links act, however when a link is set to open in a new window/tab (<a target="some_target">) to open in the same tab, as though that had not been set.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like it's possible. Found another one who wanted this: http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-614308.html

I guess the only thing left to do is write hatemail to Jobs. :)

Comment: Oh, that's too bad